# Issue related to the usage of the library Chart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, chart.js, lazy-loading

I am facing a strange issue related to the usage of the library Chart.js

Here down bellow is my codesandbox link

https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-night-2fubr?file=/src/views/Dashboard.js

You will notice that there is no graph in the performance card
[image]

However if I am going to change any element in the code, while debuging the app you can see the graph loaded...
For instance... We have the boolean `let changethis = true;` in the line 53 of the `Dashboard.js` file if we put that to false we will still not be able to see anything on the page... However if we put it again to its original value we then will see the graph down bellow...

[image]

I think that it maybe should be something related to the performance... Could someone please give me an adive on how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem above just by inserting investments on the userEffects as you can see in the line 128   `}, [investments]);`
However now it is messaging continuously

```
Fetch finished loading: GET "<URL>". in the console...
```

Does anyone there know how to solve this problem?